# Rust send serialized struct from crossbeam channel to multiple receivers via tcp

Tags: rust, tcp, crossbeam

I am trying to send a serialized struct over tcp to multiple machines. The tcp handler receives the serialized struct (String type) by a crossbeam channel from another thread.
My problem is that the rx.try_iter() will drain the crossbeam channel, and if more than one client is connected the clients can't receive the same struct. I tried moving the rx.try_iter() out of the individual handle_client() function, but couldn't achieve a good result.
Thanks for your time and help!

This is what I have so far:

(Server side)

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;
use std::io::{Read,Write,Error};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use crossbeam_channel::unbounded;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Serialized {
    pub buffer: Vec<u32>,
    pub timestep: u128,
}

impl Serialized {
    pub fn serialize(buffer: Vec<u32>, timestep: u128) -> String {
        let x = Serialized {
           buffer,
           timestep 
        };
        serde_json::to_string(&x).unwrap()
    }
}

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream, rx: crossbeam_channel::Receiver<String>)-> Result<(), Error> {
    println!("incoming connection from: {}", stream.peer_addr()?);
    loop {
        //receive from channel
        let serialized = match rx.try_iter().last(){
            Some(x) => x,
            None => continue,
        };

        //write to stream
        stream.write(serialized.as_bytes())?;
    }
}

pub fn start_server(rx: crossbeam_channel::Receiver<String>) {
    
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8888").expect("Could not bind");
    
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let rx = rx.clone();
        match stream {
            Err(e)=> {eprintln!("failed: {}", e)}
            Ok(stream) => {
                
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    handle_client(stream, rx).unwrap_or_else(|error| eprintln!("{:?}", error));
                });
                
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

(Client side)

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use std::error::Error as er;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Serialized {
    pub buffer: Vec<u32>,
    pub timestep: u128,
}

fn read_user_from_stream(tcp_stream: &mut TcpStream) -> Result<Serialized, Box<dyn er>> {
    let mut de = serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(tcp_stream);
    let u = Serialized::deserialize(&mut de)?;

    Ok(u)
}

pub fn start_client() {
    loop {
        let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8888").expect("could not connect");
        let serialized = read_user_from_stream(&mut stream).unwrap();
        println!("timestep: {}", serialized.timestep);
    }
}

fn main() {
    start_client();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`crossbeam` does not offer broadcast functionality](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/issues/374). `crossbeam` only provides a producer-consumer architecture; if you want to deliver an item to multiple receivers, you need to use a different mechanism.

It seems that the [`bus`](https://docs.rs/bus) crate provides what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it seems like the right direction for sure! I looked into the bus crate, and it seems that the bounded nature of bus means that once the channel is full, a new message can only be broadcast if all receivers successfully received the old messages. Im also still not sure how to set up the sending and receiving part properly. When I am broadcasting in the main loop using bus, I can't move bus into the function which handles the client. I don't know how to give each client an own BusReader.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Open a new one in stackoverflow, show us the code you have (Minimalized), then we can talk about it.

Comment: The way this answer is phrased, makes it sound like you can't use crossbeam to broadcast messages. While you could use crossbeam to implement a solution for broadcasting messages, which uses multiple senders internally

Comment: Sure, of course. But that wouldn't be a broadcast, that would be multiple point to point connections. The term 'broadcast' to me sounds like it shouldn't matter to the sender how many receivers exist. Either way, rephrased it. Hopefully it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion on the rust user board, I came to this solution (server side):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Read,Write,Error};
use bus::{Bus, BusReader};

fn main() {
    let mut x: u32 = 0;
    let bus = Bus::<u32>::new(10);

    let bus_mutex = Arc::new(Mutex::new(bus));

    let bus_mutex_cp = Arc::clone(&bus_mutex);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        start_server(bus_mutex_cp);
    });

    //simulation loop
    for _ in 0..99999 {
        x = x + 1;
        println!("Simulation step: {}", x);
        bus_mutex.lock().unwrap().broadcast(x);
        thread::sleep_ms(1000);
    }

    loop {}

}


pub fn start_server(bus_mutex: Arc<Mutex<Bus<u32>>>) {
    
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8888").expect("Could not bind");
    
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        
        match stream {
            Err(e)=> {eprintln!("failed: {}", e)}
            Ok(stream) => {
                
                let rx = bus_mutex.lock().unwrap().add_rx();
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    handle_client(stream, rx).unwrap_or_else(|error| eprintln!("{:?}", error));
                });
                
            }
        } 

    }
}

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream, mut rx: BusReader<u32>)-> Result<(), Error> {
    println!("incoming connection from: {}", stream.peer_addr()?);
    loop {
        //receive from bus
        let x = rx.recv().unwrap();

        //write to stream
        stream.write(&x.to_string().as_bytes())?;

        thread::sleep_ms(100);
    }
}
```